# Django channels and websocket not working

Tags: django, websocket, django-channels

I've checked all the related questions none of them helped me. I'm making a simple application where I will get JSON responses on the websocketking.com site. No matter how many times I make changes none of the tries are working.
here every detail

### asgi.py file

```
import os

from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
from django.urls import path
from home.consumers import *

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'core.settings')

ws_patterns = [
    path('ws/test/', TestConsumer),
]


application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "http": get_asgi_application(),
    "websocket": AuthMiddlewareStack(URLRouter(ws_patterns)),
})
```

### consumers.py file

```
from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync
import json

class TestConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):

    def connect(self):
        self.room_name = "test_consumer"
        self.room_group_name = "test_consumer_group"
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(self.room_name, self.room_group_name)
        self.accept()
        self.send(text_data=json.dumps({'status' : 'connected'}))

    def receive(self):
        pass

    def disconnect(self):
        pass
```

### These are the things I added in my settings.py file

```
ASGI_APPLICATION = 'core.asgi.application'

CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {
            "hosts": [("localhost", 6379)],
        },
    },
}
```

### And here is the error I got in console

```
WebSocket HANDSHAKING /ws/test/ [127.0.0.1:2795]
Exception inside application: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\PythonProjects\channels_project\env\lib\site-packages\channels\staticfiles.py", line 44, in __call__
    return await self.application(scope, receive, send)
  File "D:\PythonProjects\channels_project\env\lib\site-packages\channels\routing.py", line 71, in __call__
    return await application(scope, receive, send)
  File "D:\PythonProjects\channels_project\env\lib\site-packages\channels\sessions.py", line 47, in __call__
    return await self.inner(dict(scope, cookies=cookies), receive, send)
  File "D:\PythonProjects\channels_project\env\lib\site-packages\channels\sessions.py", line 254, in __call__
    return await self.inner(wrapper.scope, receive, wrapper.send)
  File "D:\PythonProjects\channels_project\env\lib\site-packages\channels\auth.py", line 181, in __call__
    return await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "D:\PythonProjects\channels_project\env\lib\site-packages\channels\middleware.py", line 26, in __call__
    return await self.inner(scope, receive, send)
  File "D:\PythonProjects\channels_project\env\lib\site-packages\channels\routing.py", line 150, in __call__
    return await application(
  File "D:\PythonProjects\channels_project\env\lib\site-packages\asgiref\compatibility.py", line 33, in new_application
    instance = application(scope)
  File "D:\PythonProjects\channels_project\env\lib\site-packages\channels\generic\websocket.py", line 23, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)
WebSocket DISCONNECT /ws/test/ [127.0.0.1:2795]
```

Comment: What does `ws_patterns = [
    path('ws/test/', TestConsumer),
]` do?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you've already solved this issue but here's some things I've noticed with your code which might help you:

1. Change WebsocketConsumer to AsyncWebsocketConsumer- Then change your consumer methods to async, e.g.

```
    async def connect(self):
        ...
```

2. Change

```
    async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(self.room_name, 
        self.room_group_name)
```

to

```
    await self.channel_layer.group_add(
        self.room_name,
        self.room_group_name)
```

As a side note:
You don't need to do self.send(msg) to check if you are connected. This is handled in self.accept() and will return to

```
    client.onopen = () => {
        console.log("connected");
    }
```

If none of these sort your problem it may be an issue with your routing and/or the middleware stack. I have had issues with authentication recently. Try using a different browser if you're using Chrome and see if you can tag onto the `onerror` event